# How To Change Text Inside a WooCommerce Email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

Hi there,

Feel stupid not being able todo this.

How do I change the text below "Notes:" to "Flight numbers, etc."

I know it's something todo with the woocommerce_email_customer_details action but I don't know to do.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried this?

```
add_filter( "woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields", "so_edit_my_note_field" );

function so_edit_my_note_field( $fields ) {
    if ( isset( $fields['customer_note'] ) ) {
        $fields['customer_note']['label']   =   "Flight numbers";
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

You can see the filter in this file of line - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-emails.php#L363

Good luck